# Change the contents of a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the contents of the div with id #latestgames when i click an anchor tag. This code is just before the closing body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
$("a").click(function(){
   if($(this).attr("id") == "web") {
      $("#latestgames").html("<div>

            </div>")
   }
   else if($(this).attr("id") == "app") {
      $("#latestgames").html("<div>

            </div>")
   }
else if($(this).attr("id") == "uni") {
      $("#latestgames").html("<div>

            </div>")
   }
   else if($(this).attr("id") == "other") {
      $("#latestgames").html("<div>

            </div>")
       }
    });
});     
</script>
```

The contents of each div will be filled with a ul if thats relevant. The list of anchor tags is as follows

```
<li class="portfolio"><a id="web" href="javascript:void(0);">Web Development</a></li>
<li class="portfolio"><a id="app" href="javascript:void(0);">Web Development</a></li>
<li class="portfolio"><a id="uni" href="javascript:void(0);">Web Development</a></li>
<li class="portfolio"><a id="other" href="javascript:void(0);">Web Development</a></li>
```

In the head i call the following

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax
/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Any insight as to what I might be doing wrong would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please update your post to indicate what you expect to happen and what incorrect thing is happening now. Include any behaviors or errors that are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is your newline which causes an unterminated statement (You should look at console for any errors, that will give you some clue):

```
$("#latestgames").html("<div>

    </div>")
```

Also Simplify your code:

```
$(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
       var id = this.id; //get the id and cache it
        var html = "";
        switch (id) { //switch the value
            case "web":
                html = "somehtml";
                break;
            case "app":
                html = "somehtml";
                break;
            case "uni":
                html = "somehtml";
                break;
            case "other":
                html = "somehtml";
                break;
        }
       $("#latestgames").html(html); // set the html
    });
});
```

calling `$(this).attr("id")` manytimes isn't good also just access the id with `this.id`, dont disturb jquery for that...

Comment: Hi @PSL, I tried using your switch statement but still no luck. Could you give me a simple example of what would replace "somehtml";

Comment: @IanButler Define "no luck". What happens instead of what you expect.

Comment: The problem is mot with your code but with the html i am using namely <ul><li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/portfolioCircle.png" /></li></ul> it works fine if i just add some simple p text

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in javascript you can't open a string on a line and close it multiple lines after.

You should replace

```
  $("#latestgames").html("<div>

    </div>")
}
```

with

```
  $("#latestgames").html("<div></div>")
}
```

Comment: That worked to some extent. I tested it with an unordered list within the div containing some simple text and it worked. What I actually want is a list of images. I tried entered the following code and it stopped working?    <ul><li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/portfolioCircle.png" /></li></ul>

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is a bit more elegant and offers greater flexibility for writing the contents of the div. I hope it might be useful to someone. This goes just before the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu ul li a').click(function(){
    $('#web').load('portfolio.html #' + $(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

The following HTML went in the required webpage:

```
<div>
    <nav id="menu">
    <ul class="portfolionav">
        <li class="portfolionav"><a href="web">Web Development</a></li>
    <li class="portfolionav"><a href="app">App Development</a></li>
    <li class="portfolionav"><a href="uni">University/Early Work</a></li>
    <li class="portfolionav"><a href="other">Other Stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="web">
    <!--Any default HTML goes in here-->
</div>
```

The Javascript references a html file I created and uploaded to the server called portfolio.html. That file contains the following:

```
<div id="web">
    <!--Any required HTML goes in here-->
</div>

<div id="app">
    <!--Any required HTML goes in here-->   
</div>

<div id="uni">
    <!--Any required HTML goes in here-->   
</div>

<div id="other">
    <!--Any required HTML goes in here-->   
</div>
```